# Photometer / Colormeter

Tags: peripherals, sensor, camera

I am wondering if there is a photometer/colormeter sensor that would be easily plugged into a raspberry pi.
I am looking at driving my Philips HUE from the exterior light color, to brighten my apartment with very natural colors. Any help highly appreciated

Comment: I think a light or color light sensor would be disappointing. You would mostly get some whitish color, when measuring outdoor lighting. If you want more hue, you should use a webcam and compute a segmentation / find out colored parts. OpenCV might help in that respect, but that is just a wild guess.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of sensors you could use. The only restriction is that they can not be analog devices since RaspberryPi does not have analog to digital converters (unless you use some external A/D chip, which isn't that hard).

You should search for something like `i2c light sensor`. Just ensure it is 3.3V compatible. [Here's](http://www.adafruit.com/products/439) an example from Adafruit. They even have a thread on their [forum](http://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=34922&start=0&sid=ed0dc7ef363e6828414adbdbb3de11e9) about using it with RaspberryPi.